# print_tensor KeyError: '/device:CPU:0'

Tags: python, debugging, tensorflow, keyerror

I'm trying to use tfdbg in ver 1.7.0 tensorflow on an AWS GPU (p2-xlarge).

When I try to either print_tensor or node_info I get a KeyError:

```
print_tensor gradients/TopKV2_grad/Gather_1:0

Error occurred during handling of command: print_tensor gradients/TopKV2_grad/Gather_1:0:                                                                   
<class 'KeyError'>: '/device:CPU:0'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usrnm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/debugger_cli_common.py", line 666, in dispatch_command
    output = handler(argv, screen_info=screen_info)
  File "/home/usrnm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/analyzer_cli.py", line 930, in print_tensor
    watch_keys = self._debug_dump.debug_watch_keys(node_name)
  File "/home/usrnm/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/lib/debug_data.py", line 1365, in debug_watch_keys
    if node_name not in self._debug_watches[device_name]:
KeyError: '/device:CPU:0'
```

I'm running a script in which I haven't done any manual assignment of devices or used clusterspec, basically am just letting tf handle the devices.

I tried checking out the tf code referenced in traceback but is a little beyond me.

Any clues why tfdbg is unhappy?

Thank you!

Edit #1:
This seems to happen when I've

1. chosen 'run' then received a message '!!! An error occurred during the run !!!'
2. then typed either

   - 'lt' then print_tensor *tensorname* or
   - 'ni -a -d -t *opname*'